# Making an OAuth connection from a Windows application to a Google App Engine application

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, oauth

We have a Windows 7 Task Tray application that needs to access services in our Google App Engine application, and we are having difficulty making the OAuth connection between them work.  For some reason our OAuth libraries that work with the Twitter and Tumblr OAuth implementations do not seem to work in this scenario with Google.  Google is returning a 400 bad request response to the last step in the OAuth authorization sequence.

To debug the problem I am trying to use Google's OAuth 1.0 Playground page  (http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/index.php). But I can't figure out what should be entered for the "scope" in step 1.  If I enter the name of our GAE server the sequence will fail with the error message "Invalid scope".  Clearly, choosing one of the provided scopes (the Google API services) is not an option for us.

Can anybody tell me how the OAuth scope designation should be set when accessing Google App Engine hosted services?

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate a google account or something else?

Answer (score 1):

just for reference look at this blog,looks helpful in your case

http://ikaisays.com/2011/05/26/setting-up-an-oauth-provider-on-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 0):

I think this [Google Official Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview) explains best how to set up an endpoint to your own appengine application. You question isn't very specific, but take note of the following that is being written in this document:

> The scope of an authorization, how much the consumer is allowed to access, is for all of a single app. App Engine only supports whole-app scopes, and does not support more granular scope requests. When Google Accounts prompts the user to authorize a consumer, the prompt explains that the consumer is requesting permission to access the full app.

And did you set up OAuth on your domain?

> The consumer performs OAuth actions using a set of standard web service endpoints. These endpoints use reserved paths on your app's domain. For example, if your app uses a Google Apps domain of www.example.com, the endpoints for the OAuth protocol begin as follows:
>
> https://www.example.com/_ah/OAuth...